# Getting values from labels and adding together in another label

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the int values from my labels and pass them to another label and add them together. In the code below, `kicklabel`, `handballlabel`, `marklabel`, etc., all need to add up and equal into `fantasylabel`. Based on how this code is set up, I'm not sure how to perform that.

I want to be able to add more lines of labels also, so that any amount of the array of labels add to a fantasy label.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var kickLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var handballLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var markLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tackleLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goalLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var freeForLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var freeAgainstLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fantasyLabel: UILabel!

    var counters: [UILabel: Int] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for label: UILabel in [kickLabel1,handballLabel1,markLabel1,tackleLabel1,goalLabel1,pointLabel1, freeForLabel1, freeAgainstLabel1, fantasyLabel] {
            counters[label] = 0

            for direction: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection in [.up, .down, .left, .right] {
                let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didSwipe(_:)))
                swipeGesture.direction = direction
                label.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
                label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                label.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func didSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let label = gestureRecognizer.view as? UILabel else { return }

        debugPrint("\(gestureRecognizer.direction)")

        switch gestureRecognizer.direction {
        case .up:
            counters[label] = counters[label]! + 10
            print(counters)
        case .down:
            counters[label] = 0
            print(counters)
        case .left:
            counters[label] = counters[label]! - 1
            print(counters)
        case .right:
            counters[label] = counters[label]! + 1
            print(counters)
        default:
            counters[label] = 0
        }

        label.text = "\(counters[label]!)"
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I have it like this, and I'm very new to this so I know it's completely wrong, is that so when you swipe the label, in any of the directions, it updates the value of that label. I'm sure there's a better way to do that, I'm just not sure how that is.

Comment: Actually, after looking again, you are doing what I was referring to. Your `counters` dictionary is using `Int` to track the data and you update the labels based on the number.

Comment: Yeah, so I think i have fantasyLabel in the wrong place, i need to do some math on the other ones, and pass that into fantasyLabel. Example :kickLabel + handballLabel + markLabel = fantasyLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your `didSwipe` you need to sum all of the `Int` values stored in your `counters` dictionary. Then update your `fantasy` label with that sum.

```
let sum = counters.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
fantasyLabel.text = "\(sum)"
```

And you probably don't want a gesture on the `fantasy` label since that value is read-only based on the sum of the other data.

I would also get rid of the individual label outlets except for the `fantasy` label. Use an IBOutletCollect to store an array of `UILabel`.

Comment: So under label.text = "\(counter[label]!)" i have fantasyLabel = "\(kickLabel1 + handballLabel1)", but thats throwing an error: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'UILabel!' operands. Sorry, im very new! Im trying to learn!

Comment: No, don't use the labels. Use the numbers. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok great, thats works, my only problem now is each int, in the fantasy context will equal a different value, so kickLabel will say 1, but in needs to equal 3 in fantasy terms, 1 handball = 1, 1 mark = 3 and so on. I thought it might have been easier to figure out than this

Comment: Sounds like you need a `struct` with a title, score, and multiplier.